# Animation of TabSet SmartGwt

Tags: animation, tabs, smartgwt

I'm trying to add an animation in the TabSet of SmartGwt Tabs for an effect [similar to that](http://gwt.googleusercontent.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwTabLayoutPanel) of the method GWT: tabPanel.setAnimationDuration(1000);

But it does nothing, this is the code:

```
    final TabSet topTabSet = new TabSet();
    topTabSet.setAnimateMoveTime(1000);
    topTabSet.setTabBarPosition(Side.TOP);
    topTabSet.setWidth(400);
    topTabSet.setHeight(200);

    Tab tTab1 = new Tab("Blue", "pieces/16/pawn_blue.png");
    Img tImg1 = new Img("pieces/48/pawn_blue.png", 48, 48);
    tTab1.setPane(tImg1);

    Tab tTab2 = new Tab("Green", "pieces/16/pawn_green.png");
    Img tImg2 = new Img("pieces/48/pawn_green.png", 48, 48);
    tTab2.setPane(tImg2);
```

None of animation work on TabSet.

I hope you help me to make it work.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To what I understand, `setAnimateMove` is inherited from `Canvas` so it would be used to animate the position change of the whole tabset from one place to another.
In the case of Gwt TabLayoutPanel fromversion 2.3 the method `setAnimationDuration` is not inherited from `ResizeComposite` and it   set the duration of the animated transition between tabs. 
So you would have probably to animate the content of your tab using the selection events.